# Python работа Schedule в отдельном потоке

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, schedule

Данный код запускает бесконечный цикл:

```
import schedule 
import time 

# Код ...

def geeks(): 
    print("Get ready") 

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(geeks) 

while True: 
    schedule.run_pending() 
    time.sleep(1)

# Еще код ...
```

Мне нужно чтобы этот цикл выполнялся отдельным потоком и не блокировал работу всей программы. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Мне нужно чтобы этот цикл выполнялся отдельным потоком и не блокировал
>   работу всей программы. Как это реализовать?

Использовать `Thread`.

Что-то вроде такого получится:

```
import schedule 
import time 
from threading import Thread

# Код ...

def geeks(): 
    print("Get ready") 

def run():
    schedule.every(10).minutes.do(geeks) 

    while True: 
        schedule.run_pending() 
        time.sleep(1)

thread = Thread(target=run)
thread.start()

# Еще код ...
```