# Данные в таблицу заносятся дважды

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой код, который берет данные с api и заносит их в бд. Если оставить как сейчас, то записанные данные в бд дублируются(при одном вызове функции `run_schedule_reg`). Когда удаляю все что связанно со вторым поток , данные не дублируются. Никак не пойму в чем тут проблема.  В первом потоке я записываю данные в бд. Во втором их достаю из б.д.

```
import requests, time, datetime, json, schedule, sqlite3
from threading import Thread

conn = sqlite3.connect('parser.sqlite', check_same_thread = False)
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reg/'


def get_registers(date):
    full_page = requests.get(url, auth=("admin","admin"))
    pars=json.loads(full_page.content.decode('utf-8'))
    a=sorted(pars, key=lambda pars: pars['time_visit'])
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with conn:
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `register` (`time` STRING, `number_car` VARCHAR)")
        for i in a:
            if i['date_visit']==date:
                number_car=i["number_car"]
                time_visit=i["time_visit"]
                cursor.execute("insert into register values (?, ?)", (time_visit, number_car))
        conn.commit()
    cursor.close()

def run_schedule_reg():         
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    date = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    schedule.every(1).minutes.do(get_registers,date)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


def print_time_visit(time_now): 
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with conn:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `register`")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            index=2
            time_db=row[0][:index] + row[0][index+1:]
            time_now_to_int =time_now[:index] + time_now[:index]
            if abs(int(time_db) - int(time_now_to_int) ) < 30:
                print(row[0], row[1])
    cursor.close()  

def run_schedule_time():            
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_now = now.strftime("%H:%M")
    schedule.every(5).minutes.do(print_time_visit,time_now)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


thread1 = Thread(target=run_schedule_reg).start()
thread2 = Thread(target=run_schedule_time).start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас два треда выполняют задачи из одной очереди. Скорее всего при schedule.run_pending() задачи копируются и второй тред успевает их увидеть до того как первый снимит их с очереди

Второй тред убери, а таймер добавь в первый

Вот эта часть должна быть только один раз

```
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Сам код в таком виде.

```
import requests, time, datetime, json, schedule, sqlite3
from threading import Thread

conn = sqlite3.connect('parser.sqlite', check_same_thread = False)
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reg/'


def get_registers(date):
    full_page = requests.get(url, auth=("admin","admin"))
    pars=json.loads(full_page.content.decode('utf-8'))
    a=sorted(pars, key=lambda pars: pars['time_visit'])
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with conn:
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `register` (`time` STRING, `number_car` VARCHAR)")
        for i in a:
            if i['date_visit']==date:
                number_car=i["number_car"]
                time_visit=i["time_visit"]
                cursor.execute("insert into register values (?, ?)", (time_visit, number_car))
        conn.commit()
    cursor.close()

def run_schedule_reg():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_now = now.strftime("%H:%M")
    schedule.every(5).minutes.do(print_time_visit,time_now) # перенесем сюда

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    date = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    schedule.every(1).minutes.do(get_registers,date)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


def print_time_visit(time_now): 
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with conn:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `register`")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            index=2
            time_db=row[0][:index] + row[0][index+1:]
            time_now_to_int =time_now[:index] + time_now[:index]
            if abs(int(time_db) - int(time_now_to_int) ) < 30:
                print(row[0], row[1])
    cursor.close()  

thread1 = Thread(target=run_schedule_reg).start()
# убрать thread2 = Thread(target=run_schedule_time).start()
```

Ещё тут момент `time_now = now.strftime("%H:%M")` нужно перенести в функцию если нужно время исполнения

Comment: прочитал про `schedule`, получается `run_pending()` запустит те команды, что были даны очереди через `do()`? тогда как раскидать их в разные очереди допустим?

Comment: Зачем? У вас же просто вывод времени

Comment: я не автор вопроса)) просто увидел код и решил разобраться..

Comment: @finally там есть пример в доках. Раскидать можно через очередь..

Comment: я вас правильно понял что мне надо 2 поток удалить а в первом сделать так? 
`thread1 = Thread(target=run_schedule_time).start()` ?

Comment: Нет, зачем вам второй поток сдесь?

Comment: не выводит print со 2ой функции. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1037658/355827
я пытался сделать на подобии этого, т.к  `schedule` блокировал вывод времени из бд.

Comment: а это моя ошибка, все работает, забыл добавить данные в api. спасибо!